# jHipster error after change to prod profile

Tags: libraries, jhipster

I've been developing my app in 'dev' profile, and everything was working fine. Then I've tried to change to 'prod' so I can deploy it to Heroku. I've run `./mvnw -Pprod`
Now I'm getting this error:
[image]

All libraries are crashed..
Here is my Project tree:

[image]

And in index.html I included all libraries like this:

```
<script src="bower_components/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to copy all libraries from _src_ to _target_ folder at same path. But I'm not sure why is't that done automatically.

Comment: have you built with -Pprod ? All dependencies are automatically added by gulp based on bower.json  so editing manually index.html does not work as your changes will be overwritten by gulp build process and bower components will get minified and concatenated.

Comment: Yep, thats the problem. What should I do then?
Localy I can copy file to target folder, but I need to deploy app to Heroku and it doesn't work that way. I have angular-bootstrap-calendar in my bower.json but it still makes problem.

Comment: This is something you have to solve in your bower.json by overriding main property from problematic dependencies, see example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100820/im-trying-to-use-ag-grid-in-angular1-project/41103837